# Using GLUT to resize game board as the window is resized

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am creating a connect 4 game, and I already implemented all of the c++ code, but now I am creating graphics.

I cannot figure out how to recenter  the game board as the window is resized. This is the code I have currently:

```
void reshape(int w, int h){
glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
width = w;
height = h;

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1.0, 1.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}
```

This is a picture of what is happening currently:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your game is `gameWidth` x `gameHeight` big, you want to find margins for it to fill the window. So first compare the game aspect ratio with the window aspect ratio to see which side to add the margins to:

```
double windowAspect = (double)w / h;
double gameAspect = (double)gameWidth / gameHeight;

if(gameAspect > windowAspect)
{
    //game is wider than the window, apply margins on top and bottom
    //...
}
else
{
    //window is wider than the game, apply margins left and right
    //...
}
```

I will only explain the first case. The second case is similar.

In the first case, there will be no margins left and right. So the final projection width should be equal to the game width. The top and bottom margins are then defined by the part of the screen that is not filled by the game:

```
double windowHeightInGameSpace = gameWidth / windowAspect;
double margin = (windowHeightInGameSpace - gameHeight) / 2;
glOrtho(0, gameWidth, -margin, gameHeight + margin, -1.0, 1.0);
```